# How to draw arrows extending perpendicularly from a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

What is the best way to draw small arrows pointing outwards of a circle all the way around it?

I made a small sample below (non-TikZ), but I'd rather do this is TikZ.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is easier than comsol I hope :)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[red] (0,0) circle (3mm);
\draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\foreach \x in {1,...,20}{\draw[ultra thick,-latex] ({\x*360/20}:2cm) -- ++({\x*360/20}:1cm);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Golfing ? `\foreach~in{1,...,20}\draw[ultra thick,-latex,rotate=~*18](2,0)--(3,0);`

Comment: @Kpym haha it's been some time. I don't think I can beat that

Comment: @percusse I agree it's too simple : not very interesting ... may be the next time ;)

Comment: @percusse oh I can do better : `\foreach~in{0,18,...,342}\draw[ultra thick,-latex](~:2)--(~:3);`

Comment: @Kpym Ah, Nice.